# Deploy pytorch .pth model in a python script

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, computer-vision

After successfully training my yolact model using a custom dataset I'm happy with the inference results outputted by eval.py using this command from anaconda terminal:

```
python eval.py --trained_model=./weights/yolact_plus_resnet50_abrasion_39_10000.pth --config=yolact_resnet_abrasion_config --score_threshold=0.8 --top_k=15 --images=./images:output_images
```

Now I want to run this inference from my own python script instead of using the anaconda terminal.
I wanna be able to get the bounding boxes of detections made on webcam frames obtained by this code below. Any idea ?

```
import cv2

src = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = src.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(5)
    if key == (27):
        break
```

The eval.py code is here at Yolact repository https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/blob/master/eval.py

Comment: For answering this question, one needs to know what is inside your `eval.py` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just write the pseudocode here for you.

Step 1: Try loading the model using the lines starting from [here](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/blob/57b8f2d95e62e2e649b382f516ab41f949b57239/eval.py#L1097) and ending [here](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/blob/57b8f2d95e62e2e649b382f516ab41f949b57239/eval.py#L1103)

Step 2: Use this [function](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/blob/57b8f2d95e62e2e649b382f516ab41f949b57239/eval.py#L595) for evaluation. Instead of cv2.imread, you just need to send your *frame*

Step 3:  Follow this [function](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/blob/57b8f2d95e62e2e649b382f516ab41f949b57239/eval.py#L135) to get the bounding boxes. Especially this [line](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/blob/57b8f2d95e62e2e649b382f516ab41f949b57239/eval.py#L149). Just trackback the 't' variable and you will get your bounding boxes.

Hope it helps. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Following thoose steps I could modify the eval.py and get evaluation and bounding boxes.  Thank you very much for the answer, very helpful :D